# Find mongo docs with empty object in array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a Mongo collection with an array property, and the array has "empty" objects in it. What query can I use to target these non-empty arrays that have only {}?

I've tried combinations of `$exists` and `$where` to no avail.

Examples of data I need to target:

```
"arrayProperty" : [ {} ]
```

and

```
"arrayProperty" : [ {}, {} ]
```

EDIT:

Here's an example of the schema:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53b1ca583d597ce7cbd54646"),
    "arrayProperty" : [ 
        {
            "serialNumber" : "abc123",
            "rfid" : "xyz098",
            "size" : 95,
            "points" : 50,
            "frequency" : "Every day",
            "dateAssigned" : ISODate("2011-02-10T15:27:39.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for docs where ANY property contains an empty document? How about if it is not at root level such as prop1: {prop2: {}}

Comment: Are you looking to find docs where `arrayProperty` contains _only_ `{}` objects?  For example, should `arrayProperty: [ {}, {a: 1} ]` match?

Comment: I'm looking for root properties such as doc.arrayProperty: [{}]. There are also some like doc.arrayProperty: [{}, {}]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking to find docs where `arrayProperty` contains at least one `{}` then it's just:

```javascript
db.collection.find({ arrayProperty: {} })
```

If you're looking to find docs where `arrayProperty` *only* contains either one or two `{}`:

```javascript
db.collection.find({ arrayProperty: {$in: [ [{}], [{}, {}] ] } })
```

Comment: I set up a dedicated test collection, and this worked!. I also tested @Trust's solution on the test collection, and that worked too. I'm going to try to flag both answers as correct...hopefully I can. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following may/may-not work...

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$unwind: {"$arrayProperty"}},
{$match: {arrayProperty: {} }},
{$group: {_id: "$_id"} }
])
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is `unwind` `arrayProperty`, pull out all documents with an `arrayProperty` as `{}`, and `group` all of the unwinded documents back that have the same `_id` (or you can replace that with whatever unique key field you use).

Again, I don't know for sure if this will work so try it out and let me know.

Comment: Didn't seem to work. I had to remove the { } around "$arrayProperty". Even with that I got..

{
    "result" : [],
    "ok" : 1
}

Comment: Could you perhaps include the schema of a typical document in your question? In any case, you might want to try experimenting with `aggregation` and see if you can come up with anything.

Comment: I updated the question to include an example of the schema. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm... okay I have to say I'm pretty stumped (sorry). Are you using a driver (eg: the Python driver or the Java driver)? If so, you could potentially just loop through `arrayProperty` from the driver itself and check if each element is an empty document. Unfortunately I'm not sure how else to do it... perhaps JohnnyHK's answer may work but that assumes that you know the maximum amount of empty docs `arrayProperty` could hold.

Comment: I set up a dedicated test collection, and this worked!. I also tested @JohnnyHK's solution on the test collection, and that worked too. I'm going to try to flag both answers as correct...hopefully I can. Thanks.

Comment: I can't identify two answers as the solution. This one works, but @JohnnyHK's is a little cleaner and providers the collection doc, not just the _id, so I'm going to flag that as the answer.

Comment: No problem! Glad both answers helped. By the way, if you want to provide the entire document while using the aggregation framework, simply add a `$project` subdocument to the pipeline I mentioned in my answer (see here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/). Just a small note for the future in case you need it.